# Programa de Java para comprobar letra dni

Tags: java

Que estoy haciendo mal? El usuario tiene que introducir por teclado su dni completo incluyendo letra (ej 19452100G) el programa tiene que decir si la letra es correcta o no. Si no es correcta el program responde con la letra correcta

```
       
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("Entra DNI completo incluyendo letra sin espacio: ");
           String numID = sc.nextLine();
           char letter_corresponde = calculateLetter(numID);
           System.out.printf("letra que corresponde %s is %c \n", numID, letter_corresponde);
           if (numID.charAt(numID.length()-1) == letter_corresponde)
               System.out.println("la letra corresponde con el DNI");
           else {
               System.out.println("Corriguiendo la letra");
               numID = numID.substring(0,numID.length()-1) + letter_corresponde;
               System.out.println(numID);
           }
               
       }
       public static char calculateLetter(String numID){
           String caracteres="TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
           int id = Integer.parseInt(numID.substring(0,numID.length()-2));
           int resto = id%23;
           return caracteres.charAt(resto);
       }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida a SOe. Aunque la pregunta está bien planteada, ayudaría que afinaras más el problema. Repasa los valores intermedios (numId, id, resto) y encuentra el punto en que el valor no es el esperado. De esa forma, incluso si no sale la solución, consigues más soltura depurando programas y haces más fácil a los que te leen el identificar el problema.

Comment: Lo que sí tendrías que explicar es el problema que tiene tu programa ¿no compila? ¿Lanza una excepción? ¿funciona pero da un resultado incorrecto? ¿Qué resultado da y cuál esperabas?

Answer (score 0):

Emmy según la formula para calcular la letra dice que se deben de tomar hasta 8 cifras del documento y según tu código estas tomando los primeros 7:

```
numID.substring(0,numID.length()-2)

Lo correcto seria:

numID.substring(0,numID.length()-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en ésta línea solo deberías de restar un carácter correspondiente a la N, y no dos:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(numID.substring(0,numID.length()-2));
```

Debería de quedar:

```
//Lo que haces aquí, es eliminar el último carácter que coresponde con la letra, para que luego haga el cálculo de la división solo con los números
int id = Integer.parseInt(numID.substring(0,numID.length()-1));
```

Hasta ahora le quitabas dos caracteres, o sea, la letra y el último número, con lo que la división se efectuaba de forma errónea